# How can I make a module's configuration exportable by features?

Tags: features, importing-exporting

At a high level, what needs to be undertaken to take a module's configuration data and make it exportable by [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features)?

Whether this is a contrib module that does not yet have Features support or a custom module that I have written, where can I start so that I can get it in code?

Comment: Too trivial: answered by looking at the readme files for the Features module.

Comment: Have to say I disagree. For one, the concept of features and exportability is not a novice issue. Secondly, if for questions like these we are just going to say, "refer to the readme", then this site will add no value over what can be found on drupal.org.

Comment: If referring to the readme is all it takes to answer a question, that speaks more about the quality of the question than the quality of the answer.

Comment: People just saying "RTFM" is the reason sites like StackOverflow were created in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instructions are in the [Features API.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/features.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/API.txt), which provides several examples of how to better integrate your module with Features.

The easiest way seems to be building your module around the [CTools Export API](http://drupalcode.org/project/ctools.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/help/export.html). Here's a [pretty good article](http://civicactions.com/blog/2009/jul/24/using_chaos_tools_module_create_exportables) explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your module is already taking advantage of the Entity API:

> specify `EntityAPIControllerExportable` as the controller class, set the `exportable` key in `hook_entity_info()` to `TRUE` and include the schema fields necessary (module, status column) by copying the schema as defined in `entity_exportable_schema_fields()` to your `hook_schema()` implementation

See the Community Docs: [Make an entity type exportable](http://drupal.org/node/1021526)

Comment: looks working .